# Make Rust code more DRY, calling C bindings is always almost identical

Tags: rust

Out of a C header file I successfully created Rust bindings with bindgen.

It is used to read many different data out of a byte array.
Each property has its own handle that has to be created in the first step and then initialize in the second step.

Because of the always same steps the code became long and unclear.

```
let mut handle_a: SDHandleA = std::ptr::null_mut();
unsafe {
    SDCreateHandleA(&mut handle_a);
    SDGetPropertyHandleA(base_handle, SD_PROPERTY_NAME_HANDLE_A, handle_a);
}
```

---

```
let mut handle_b: SDHandleB = std::ptr::null_mut();
unsafe {
    SDCreateHandleB(&mut handle_b);
    SDGetPropertyHandleB(base_handle, SD_PROPERTY_NAME_HANDLE_B, handle_b);
}
```

---

```
let mut handle_c: SDHandleC = std::ptr::null_mut();
unsafe {
    SDCreateHandleC(&mut handle_c);
    SDGetPropertyHandleC(base_handle, SD_PROPERTY_NAME_HANDLE_C, handle_c);
}
```

---

```
let mut handle_d: SDHandleD = std::ptr::null_mut();
unsafe {
    SDCreateHandleD(&mut handle_d);
    SDGetPropertyHandleD(base_handle, SD_PROPERTY_NAME_HANDLE_D, handle_d);
}
```

---

All `SDHandle..` are simply type aliases of `*mut ::std::os::raw::c_void`.

```
pub type SDHandle = *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void;
pub type SDHandleA = SDHandle;
pub type SDHandleB = SDHandle;
pub type SDHandleC = SDHandle;
pub type SDHandleD = SDHandle;
```

As Rust is capable of higher order functions, I've tried a creation-method:

```
fn create_handle<F, G, H>(
    target_type: F,
    create_step: G, 
    init_step: H,
    base_handle: c_void,
    property: *mut i8
) -> F
    where 
        F: SDHandleA, 
        G: Fn(F),
        H: Fn(c_void, *mut i8, F) {
        ..
        ..
}
```

And I called it with:

```
let mut handle_a: SDHandleA = create_handle(SDHandleA, SDCreateHandleA, SDGetPropertyHandleA, base_handle, SD_PROPERTY_NAME_HANDLE_A);
```

But Rust complains:

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found type alias `SDHandleA`
   --> src/lib.rs:379:12
    |
123 |         F: SDHandleA,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^ type aliases cannot be used as traits
```

That's right. `SDHandleA` is not a trait.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: So many colons... can you use `use`? Those long qualified names are getting in the way :(

Comment: In my source code I used ``use``, yeah. I just removed some of the long qualified names.

Comment: "All `SDHandle..` inherit from `::std::os::raw::c_void.`" This is nonsensical. Rust does not have inheritance, and even if you count supertraits, that only applies to traits, not to types.

Comment: There's probably a better way, but it's hard to help you when we don't have type definitions or any other context.

Comment: "All `SDHandle..` are simply type definitions `*mut ::std::os::raw::c_void`." You mean type aliases? Like `type SDHandleA = *mut c_void;`?

Comment: Perhaps a macro is the way to go?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm new to Rust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```rust
unsafe fn create_handle(
    creator: unsafe extern "C" fn(*mut SDHandle),
    initializer: unsafe extern "C" fn(c_void, *mut c_char, SDHandle), 
    base_handle: c_void, 
    property: *mut c_char
) -> SDHandle {
    let mut handle: SDHandle = std::ptr::null_mut();
    unsafe {
        creator(&mut handle);
        initializer(base_handle, property, handle);
    }
    handle
}
```

Note that type aliases `type X = Y` do NOT count as separate types. They are just another name for the same type. So `SDHandleA`, etc are the same type as `SDHandle`. This means you do not need a generic for the handle output.

If you want to have separate types, you should investigate the newtype pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This approach gives an error: ``error[E0277]: expected a `Fn<(*mut *mut c_void,)>` closure, found `unsafe extern "C" fn(*mut *mut c_void) {SDCreateHandleA}`
   --> src/lib.rs:123:98``. And Rust is correct. ``SDCreateHandleA`` is an unsafe extern call to  C function.

Comment: Already tried that before. Rust does not like it: ``error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `,`, `?`, `for`, `{`, `~`, lifetime, or path, found keyword `unsafe`
   --> src/lib.rs:123:12
    |
303 |         C: unsafe extern "C" fn (*mut SDHandle),
    |            ^^^^^^ expected one of 9 possible tokens
``

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't have a chance to try it. Should work now.

Comment: Wow. Who would have thought that this subtle change makes a difference. Now it works, perfect. Thank you very much.